# Working 12V ups circuit?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I've looked at similar threads on stackechange but none seem to provide an answer.

I have 2 devices running on 12v DC. One at 1A and the other at 2A.

I had an existing 12V 7Ah lead acid battery with a 0.8A charger. 
My thinking was to connect the charger to battery, then connect both devices to the battery as well and when power is lost the 2 devices will continue operating.

This failed miserably and the charger wasn't able to provide the 3A required constantly by the devices.

My question is: how would I go about powering the 2 units (12V 3Ah) from AC while there is AC and when AC is lost automatically use the battery power?

I don't mind getting my hands dirty and constructing the circuit, I just have no idea where to begin.

Thanks!
Amir

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you can find a power supply capable of delivering 12V at 3A to the two devices? Plenty of power supplies like this on ebay etc..

Use a [relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay) powered from AC - when the AC drops out the relay contact feeds your load from the battery. When the AC returns, the relay contact swaps back to feeding power to the load from the 12V power supply.

A slight refinement is to have a schottky diode connected between battery and load (in effect across the relay contacts) - the benefit of this is to always guarantee that as the contact switches there will be about 11.5 volts to power your load. Also recommended is a large ish hold up capacitor across your load (maybe 1000 uF).

Comment: Yes I can find a power supply like that, but was told that battery should not be charged with more than 10% of its capacity (10% of 7Ah is the 0.8A I have from the charger). Can I use a much larger power supply and reduce the current only for the charger?

Comment: user3855437, I believe @Andy aka's idea is as follows: Use a double-throw relay to select the power source for the load. When AC is present, select the power supply. When AC is absent, select the battery instead. The battery would never be connected to the power supply. Also, you would keep the charger connected to the battery. So when AC is present, the battery will be kept fully charged and when AC is absent, the relay would switch over to battery power. The capacitor would be connected to the load to make sure the voltage does not drop too far during the switchover.

Comment: @mkeith Yup that is it dude.

Comment: @user3855437: I've heard that flooded lead-acid batteries should not be charged at more than 20 - 25% of capacity, but gel and AGM batteries can accept faster charging, even over 100% of capacity.  However, in your case, the charger needs to supply your 3 amp load as well as charge the battery, so the charger must supply more than the 3 amps that the load requires.  A proper regulated charger should not over-charge or stress the battery.

Answer (score 0):

If your devices draw a total of 3 amps, the obvious (and simple) solution is to get a battery charger that can deliver more than 3 amps.

If the charger delivers less current than the loads use, it will only slow the discharge of the battery, not prevent it.

Comment: Peter, you are correct. But at one point (in my case about 12 hours) the battery runs out. I assume because I'm drawing 3A and the power supply (charger) only provides 0.8A so the balance of the current is coming from the battery.

Comment: He is suggesting to use a charger capable of delivering more than 3A. If it is a lead acid type of battery, you could use a power supply which floats the battery at 13.5V or so. This would keep the battery fully charged and not over-charge it. There is slight variation in the recommended float voltage depending on battery type (flooded vs. AGM vs gel cell). I believe 13.5 will work for flooded and AGM, but is too high for gel cell. Anyway, if you pursue it, research it.